# Generating SVG file of Mexico and USA at states level (Admin1) when Kartograph fails

Tags: shapefile, mac, svg

I am trying to include a US map at the state detail on top of this maps: http://crimeinmexico.org/

I am using Kartograph for the small map. I have installed kartograph in Mac OS X and I am able to generate the map of the world as shown in the kartograph tutorial.

I have downloaded the ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces from naturalearthdata. http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/

When using this json configuration (mex.json):

```
    {
"layers":  {
    "mylayer": { 
        "src": "ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp",
        "filter": { "iso_a3": "MEX" }
        }
    }
}
```

and running this command in bash: `kartograph mex.json -o mex.svg`

I get this error:

```
cli.py, in render_map()
  71: K.generate(cfg, args.output, preview=args.preview, format=format, stylesheet=css)  kartograph.py, in generate()
  46: _map = Map(opts, self.layerCache, format=format)  map.py, in __init__()
  48: me.proj = me._init_projection()  map.py, in _init_projection()
  88: map_center = self.__get_map_center()  map.py, in __get_map_center()
  140: features = self._get_bounding_geometry()  map.py, in _get_bounding_geometry()
  257: charset=layer.options['charset']  layersource/shplayer.py, in get_features()
  96: if filter is None or filter(drec):  map.py, in <lambda>()
  252: filter = lambda rec: layerFilter(rec) and boundsFilter(rec)  map.py, in <lambda>()
  239: layerFilter = lambda rec: filter_record(layer.options['filter'], rec)  filter.py, in filter_record()
  25: res = res and filter_record([key, '=', filt[key]], record)  filter.py, in filter_record()
  27: res = filter_single(filt, record)  filter.py, in filter_single()
  35: prop = record[key]
neto@Ernestos-MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/thesis/datos/naturalearthdata/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces$ kartograph mex.json -o mex.svg  cli.py, in render_map()
  71: K.generate(cfg, args.output, preview=args.preview, format=format, stylesheet=css)  kartograph.py, in generate()
  46: _map = Map(opts, self.layerCache, format=format)  map.py, in __init__()
  48: me.proj = me._init_projection()  map.py, in _init_projection()
  88: map_center = self.__get_map_center()  map.py, in __get_map_center()
  140: features = self._get_bounding_geometry()  map.py, in _get_bounding_geometry()
  257: charset=layer.options['charset']  layersource/shplayer.py, in get_features()
  96: if filter is None or filter(drec):  map.py, in <lambda>()
  252: filter = lambda rec: layerFilter(rec) and boundsFilter(rec)  map.py, in <lambda>()
  239: layerFilter = lambda rec: filter_record(layer.options['filter'], rec)  filter.py, in filter_record()
  25: res = res and filter_record([key, '=', filt[key]], record)  filter.py, in filter_record()
  27: res = filter_single(filt, record)  filter.py, in filter_single()
  35: prop = record[key]
u'iso_a3'
```

I tried using the Python module instead of the command line as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937077/kartograph-map-creation-fails/22793960#22793960

I still get errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makeMap.py", line 18, in <module>
    K.generate(config, outfile='paises.svg')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/kartograph.py", line 46, in generate
    _map = Map(opts, self.layerCache, format=format)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/map.py", line 48, in __init__
    me.proj = me._init_projection()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/map.py", line 88, in _init_projection
    map_center = self.__get_map_center()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/map.py", line 140, in __get_map_center
    features = self._get_bounding_geometry()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/map.py", line 257, in _get_bounding_geometry
    charset=layer.options['charset']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/layersource/shplayer.py", line 96, in get_features
    if filter is None or filter(drec):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/map.py", line 252, in <lambda>
    filter = lambda rec: layerFilter(rec) and boundsFilter(rec)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/map.py", line 239, in <lambda>
    layerFilter = lambda rec: filter_record(layer.options['filter'], rec)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/kartograph.py-0.6.8-py2.7.egg/kartograph/filter.py", line 29, in filter_record
    res = filt(record)
  File "makeMap.py", line 6, in myfilter
    return record['iso_a3'] in ["USA", "MEX"]
KeyError: 'iso_a3'
```

I have tried changing iso_a3 for iso, ADM0_A3 and ADM1_A3 and I get the same error.

Does anybody know what am I doing wrong or can anyone point me in the right direction?

I even tried concatenating a MEX.svg and an USA.svg file but they are rendered overlapping each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you got the column name but downloading from your link

[image: Natural Earth Download image]

Then opening in QGIS and clicking on a Mexico state, I never see an iso_a3 column but I do see adm0_a3 or gu_a3 or sov_a3 all with the same value MEX

You should better use this config file so you get both USA and MEXICO (tested and it works)

```
{    
"layers":  {    
    "mylayer": {    
        "src": "ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp",    
            "filter": { "adm0_a3": ["MEX", "USA"] }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

The result with Greenland or Hawaii Isles can be annoying. You can delete them with your vectorial drawing software or you can filter them with Kartograph.py using `not` combined with `nested expressions`. See in the docs the [detailed filter part](http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.py/filter.html).

For attributes info, see this GIF

[image: QGis attributes infos]

Answer (score -2):

I cannot answer in Kartograph but you can create SVGs in QGIS and QGIS runs on MAC.

QGIS Mac [Link](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html).

SVG in QGIS [Link](http://www.duif.net/qgis/simplesvg/).

If you check this board you will notice an earlier GIS SE question when they failed to convert shapes to SVG in Kartograph.